# How to correctly display icons on buttons

Tags: css

I'm wondering what's wrong with my code which is causing icons to be shown in a wrong way, displayed upper left and cut, rather than being correctly shown full and on center.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="simple-css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.4.1/css/simple-line-icons.min.css" type="text/css" media="all">


<div id="button-offer">
<div class="container">
<div class="text-center">
<div class="btn btn-offer btn-lg btn-watch" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#player-modal">
<span class="btn-bg"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> Read Intro
</div>
<a class="btn btn-offer btn-lg btn-download" onclick="pdf_demo_download()">
<span class="btn-bg"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> Download
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is how they are supposed to be shown: `https://images2.imgbox.com/f8/5f/4O2RA6V1_o.png`
This is how they are being actually shown: `https://images2.imgbox.com/bc/e1/7sLUZlog_o.png`

EDIT: Added CSS button code part

```
#button-offer{padding:15px 0;background:#000;}
.btn-offer:focus,.btn-offer:active{color:#fff;}
.btn-watch{background-color:#c00;}
.btn-download{background-color:#c00;}
.btn-offer{outline:none!important;color:#fff;padding:15px 20px 15px 70px;text-decoration:none;border-radius:3px;font-family:Oswald,Sans-serif;font-weight:700;letter-spacing:1px;text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000;position:relative;text-transform:uppercase}
.btn-bg{color:#fff;display:inline-block;position:absolute;width:30px;height:54px;top:0px;left:-1px;background-color:#333;border-radius:3px 0 0 3px}
.btn-bg:before{background-color:#9C360E;content:"";position:absolute;top:8px;width:38px;height:38px;background:inherit;border:inherit;border-left-color:transparent;border-bottom-color:transparent;border-radius:0 4px 0 0;-webkit-border-radius:0 4px 0 0;-moz-border-radius:0 4px 0 0;transform:rotate(45deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);-o-transform:rotate(45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(45deg);left:10px;border-right:1px solid;border-top:1px solid}
.btn-bg .icon{position:relative;top:16px;left:7px}
.btn-watch:hover{color:#fff;background-color:#6f0404;}
.btn-download:hover{color:#fff;background-color:#6f0404;}
.sub-section span, .widget-title span{background:#c00;}
```

Comment: change the `background-position` of the button's image to match the position of the icon

Comment: I have added the CSS code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Where is the button here? You supposed to use  instead of . 
the syntax should look like this
 Read Intro

and it should show icon as it supposed.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the CSS part regarding the button. Please be more accurate on your advice, I haven't understood what you told me.

Comment: So basically if you need anything clicked on you don't use <div> as you did here

<div class="btn btn-offer btn-lg btn-watch" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#player-modal">
<span class="btn-bg"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> Read Intro
</div>


You use 

<button class="btn btn-offer btn-lg btn-watch" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#player-modal"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i> Read Intro</button>

Comment: can you post full html and css file please  ?

Answer (score 0):

you just following of this code and used it

```css
#button-offer{padding:15px 0;background:#000;}
.btn-offer:focus,.btn-offer:active{color:#fff;}
.btn-watch{background-color:#c00;}
.btn-download{background-color:#c00;}
.btn-offer{outline:none!important;color:#fff;padding:15px 20px 15px 70px;text-decoration:none;border-radius:3px;font-family:Oswald,Sans-serif;font-weight:700;letter-spacing:1px;text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000;position:relative;text-transform:uppercase}
.btn-bg{color:#fff;display:inline-block;position:absolute;width:30px;height:45px;top:0px;left:-1px;background-color:#333;border-radius:3px 0 0 3px}
.btn-bg:before{background-color:#9C360E;content:"";position:absolute;top:8px;width:38px;height:28px;background:inherit;border:inherit;border-left-color:transparent;border-bottom-color:transparent;border-radius:0 4px 0 0;-webkit-border-radius:0 4px 0 0;-moz-border-radius:0 4px 0 0;transform:rotate(45deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);-o-transform:rotate(45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(45deg);left:10px;border-right:1px solid;border-top:1px solid}
.btn-bg .icon{position:relative;top:16px;left:7px}
.btn-watch:hover{color:#fff;background-color:#6f0404;}
.btn-download:hover{color:#fff;background-color:#6f0404;}
.sub-section span, .widget-title span{background:#c00;}
i{position: absolute;
  padding-top: 11px;
  font-size: 25px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" id="simple-css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" media="all">


<div id="button-offer">
<div class="container">
<div class="text-center">

<button class="btn btn-offer btn-lg btn-watch" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#player-modal"><span class="btn-bg"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> Read Intro</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```